# How to rebuild a corrupt postgres primary key index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where I have a row that cannot be found by id.  If I go around the PK index, the row is found.  If I drop the index, the row is found.  If I add a new index, row not found.

```
d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> SELECT id, created_at FROM widgets WHERE id = 1155301;
   id    |         created_at         
---------+----------------------------
 1155301 | 2014-01-10 02:59:47.856214
(1 row)

d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX widgets_pkey ON widgets(id);
CREATE INDEX
d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> SELECT id, created_at FROM widgets WHERE id = 1155301;
 id | created_at 
----+------------
(0 rows)

d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> SELECT id, created_at FROM widgets WHERE id - 1 + 1 = 1155301;
   id    |         created_at         
---------+----------------------------
 1155301 | 2014-01-10 02:59:47.856214
(1 row)

d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> DROP INDEX widgets_pkey;
DROP INDEX
d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> SELECT id, created_at FROM widgets WHERE id = 1155301;
   id    |         created_at         
---------+----------------------------
 1155301 | 2014-01-10 02:59:47.856214
(1 row)

d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX widgets_pkey ON widgets(id);
CREATE INDEX
d5toqvrtbm8bbu=> SELECT id, created_at FROM widgets WHERE id = 1155301;
 id | created_at 
----+------------
(0 rows)
```

This is on postgres 9.3

Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks really weird. You should post that to the Postgres mailing list.

Comment: It looks as if the index is corrupted as soon as it's created. What's the type of this `id` column and is there any custom code in your postgres installation?

Comment: Please show the `\d+` for the table `widgets`, and `explain` for both with-index and without-index plans. Is `id` an `integer` / `bigint`? Or something else? What's the exact `SELECT version()` ? Can you post a self-contained database dump that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A dump and restore fixes the problem, consistent with my conclusion that I've got a broken index.

Comment: I'm seeing almost the exact same problem right now myself.  I tried REINDEX which seems as though it's meant for exactly this, but it's not helping.  (Which I suppose is similar to how you're creating the index and it's instantly corrupt.)  This is on Amazon RDS with version 3.3.3.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with my database. I tried REINDEX but it didn't help.

```
VACUUM FULL widgets;
```

Totally fixed the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Looping back on this:

I worked with Heroku support (this was Heroku Postgres hosted) and they told me there was a bug in 9.3.2 that could lead to this kind of corruption when a follower was promoted.  (I experienced it on a couple of generations of promoted followers.)

They said the problem was fixed in 9.3.4, and I wound up being able to recreate the broken rows from backups, deleting the rows and then rebuilding.

So far no reoccurrence.